# How to stop infinite waiting for ZMQ recv function for a publish socket?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, pyzmq

I am having issues receiving messages from a ZMQ socket. I created a socket, binded it to an address and set up its subscription. However, when I try to receive messages from the socket the program hangs.

```
self.context = zmq.Context()
self.pub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
self.pub_socket.connect(pub_socket_addr)
self.pub_socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, value)
reply = self.pub_socket.recv()
```

We tried catching the ZMQError in an infinite loop with the NOBLOCK flag as shown in the following code, but it won't receive any data from the server either.

```
while True:
        try:
            reply = self.pub_socket.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK)
            try:
                if(json.loads(reply)[command.Command.COMM_TYPE] == command.Command.GAME_START):
                    return True
            except ValueError:
                continue
        except zmq.ZMQError:
            break
```

What could be possible issues?

Comment: please provide a more complete example, including a minimal server code and the real value of your "subscribe" socket option call

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet hangs because `recv()` only returns after it receives.

The infinite loop is `break`ing on the first iteration because the `zmq.ZMQError` exception rises since there is nothing to receive. You could try to replace the `break` instruction with `time.sleep(0.1)` to iterate until the socket receives something and the `GAMESTART` condition is meet.

The following code should do the trick:

```
got_game_start = False
while not got_game_start:
    try:
        reply = self.pub_socket.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK)
    except zmq.ZMQError:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        try:
            got_game_start = (json.loads(reply)[command.Command.COMM_TYPE] == command.Command.GAME_START)
        except:
            got_game_start = False
# at this point the loop should end after receiving the game start message
```

Comment: I did exactly the same thing as you told, but it still stuck in the loop.

Comment: But if there's nothing sent by the server, then I can't receive anything neither. So I think I should check if server is sending message to me.